# Lock association inside callback with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it permissible to lock associated object inside ActiveRecord's callback?

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  # stock (integer)

  has_many :sales
end

class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  # quantity (integer)
  
  belongs_to :product

  before_save do
    self.product.lock!
    throw :abort if self.product.stock < self.quantity
  end
end
```

The idea is prevent creating Sale records with insufficient stock.

Answer (score 1):

"Permitted" it may be but IMO it's not a good practice. Here is why I consider that:

- `Sale` should not know how to `lock` the `product`, should not know the `product` attributes. It should be as dumb as possible.
- `Sale` shouldn't dictate if it can be saved or not. IMO it should be more of a confirmation that a product was sold.
- That `lock` is [Pessimistic](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) and it is mandatory to be wrapped in a `transaction`. I'm not seeing the entire flow, but if if it's not then then rollbacks will be incomplete (it happened to me)

When dealing with sales, payments (delicate Business flows) I usually extract the code in a [Service Object](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial). It can be tested in isolation, you don't pollute models with logic out of their scope, code quality principles are followed, etc.

Here is an empirical example:

```
class PurchaseProduct
  def initialize(product, quantity)
   @product = product
   @quantity = quantity
  end

  def purchase
    Product.transaction do 
      @product.lock!
      if @product.stock >= @quantity
        product.update_attribute(:stock, @product.stock - @quantity)
        product.sales.create(quantity: @quantity)
        # other stuff to do 
        # send confirmation email, etc
      else
        throw "Something"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When writing software one very important aspect is to have loosely coupled code. You can check [Principle of least knowlede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) for more info if you are not familiar. [SRP](https://www.sitepoint.com/solid-ruby-single-responsibility-principle/) is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You may want [custom validate](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```rb
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  validate :valid_quantity

  private

  def valid_quantity
    if quantity > product.stock
      errors.add(:quantity, "can't be greater than product stock")
    end
  end
end
```

With this validation, `Sale` won't be created with insufficient stock, and have a descriptive error message.

Comment: It is very likely that the site is an e-commerce one, so race conditions are very likely to happen, hence that `lock`. This validation works for simple scenarios but will fail when multiple users purchase the same thing on Black Fridays :D